# Possible data race conditions in OpenSSL libcrypto.1.0.0 CRYPTO_malloc() reported by Helgrind

Tags: c, multithreading, openssl

I am having issues testing a multi threaded (pthreads) application with Helgrind reporting hundreds of possible data races inside CRYPTO_malloc() in libcrypto.1.0.0.

I have read and fully understood all the available documentation, including The Definative Guide to Linux Network Programming pages 255-259 and http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html.

My code is initializing the static and dynamic lock structures and callbacks, and registering the thread ID call back:

```
CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback(ssl_mitm_thread_id);
CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback(ssl_mitm_dyn_create_lock);
CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback(ssl_mitm_dyn_locking_callback);
CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback(ssl_mitm_dyn_destroy_lock);
ssl_mitm_lock_mutexes = (pthread_mutex_t*)malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() *
  sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
for(i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++) {
  pthread_mutex_init(&ssl_mitm_lock_mutexes[i], NULL);
}
CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(ssl_mitm_locking_callback);

SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
...etc...
```

I have added debug statements to the locking call back functions, and openSSL is only calling the depreciated CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(), and not using the new dynamic lock interface.

Even so, it is calling the old static lock function, so is making some attempt at thread syncronisation, but Helgrind still thinks there are lots of possible data races. Most if not all of them are within CRYPTO_malloc().

So, is this Helgrind getting over zealous or is it a bug in OpenSSL/libcrypto?

e.g.

```
==20093== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==20093==
==20093== Possible data race during write of size 4 at 0x63BA368 by thread #3
==20093== Locks held: none
==20093==    at 0x604F0FE: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==20093==    by 0x57F4186: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==20093==    by 0x57D20C4: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==20093==    by 0x57D62E1: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==20093==    by 0x57DF0B6: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
[snip] (SSL_connect() called)
==20093==
==20093== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #6
==20093== Locks held: none
==20093==    at 0x604F0FE: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==20093==    by 0x57E1673: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==20093==    by 0x57DF359: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
[snip] (SSL_connect() called)
==20093==
==20093== ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are other examples of data races in CRYPTO_malloc() called from SSL_read, SSL_write, SSL_connect and SSL_accept, and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in the snip below is the line of code Helgrind is complaining about:

```
void *CRYPTO_malloc(int num, const char *file, int line)
        {
        void *ret = NULL;

        if (num <= 0) return NULL;

        allow_customize = 0;
```

The `allow_customize` global variable is initialized to `1` in static initialization. This value is used to make sure the malloc customization functions (the `CRYPTO_set_mem...` and variations) are not called after the allocation routines themselves have been called. This setting to the value `0` is what is done outside of a lock. Technically, there is a race condition if one thread attempts to call a `CRYPTO_...alloc` function when another thread is trying to set custom functions for `CRYPTO`, but that can be considered an application bug.

Comment: I note the comment in the OpenSSL documentation, however, I am setting the locking_function call back and initialising the locks as you suggest, but Helgrind still complains of possible data races. Also, as I said in my original post, adding debug printfs to the locking_function clearly shows OpenSSL calling it, but again Helgrind still complains.

Comment: perhaps I should post to openssl-dev?

Comment: @Dan: I didn't see that you had provided the static locking callback before.

Comment: (you edited the answer so my original comment makes not sense, however). Thanks, the assignment allow_customize = 0 does seem to account for the vast majority of the possible data races.

However, there are a few more races after called SSL_accept() inside a shared SSL_CTX. I had thought that you could safely share a common SSL_CTX between many threads, perhaps it's another (if(initialised = 0)) predicate with similar semantics to this allow_customize variable and can be ignored, but would be good to get everything accounted for.

Comment: update: I thought the races in the SSL_accept/SSL_connect call chain referencing two common SSL_CTXs (one for client one for server side) might be due to the SSL CTX session caching, I tried disabling it after creating the new SSL_CTXs using SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF) but two Value4 races still occur, perhaps they are just ref-counts which never get used, so I think I'm home and dry now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where `CRYPTO_malloc` is defined:

```
$ grep -R CRYPTO_malloc *
...
crypto/mem.c:void *CRYPTO_malloc_locked(int num, const char *file, int line)
crypto/mem.c:void *CRYPTO_malloc(int num, const char *file, int line)
...
```

`CRYPTO_malloc_locked` is an attempt to keep pages in memory (and not written to `swap`); and not a thread safe allocator.

This is what `CRYPTO_malloc` does:

```
void *CRYPTO_malloc(int num, const char *file, int line)
    {
    void *ret = NULL;

    ...
    ret = malloc_ex_func(num,file,line);

    ...
    return ret;
    }
```

`malloc_ex_func` is set to `default_malloc_ex` in `CRYPTO_set_mem_functions`. And `default_malloc_ex`. But I can't seem to find an implementation of `default_malloc_ex`.

However, `CRYPTO_malloc_init` has the following:

```
#define CRYPTO_malloc_init()    CRYPTO_set_mem_functions( \
    malloc, realloc, free)
```

So it appears the C runtime's `malloc` is being used.

Is the version of OpenSSL you are using built with thread support? You can test by including `<openssl/openssl.con.h>`, and testing if `OPENSSL_THREADS` is defined.

This should also work:

```
$ cat /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/opensslconf.h | grep -B 1 -A 1 -i thread

#ifndef OPENSSL_THREADS
# define OPENSSL_THREADS
#endif
```

Comment: thanks, I am checking for OPENSSL_THREADS definition, and refuse to compile if it's not defined.

Comment: I think jxh is probably right. I did not check `allow_customize` and friends from `CRYPTO_malloc`, so I did not call them out.